# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?). for abstract class

Tags: angular

I am a newbie in angular. Here I was playing with abstract and interfaces. I am setting properties in abstract class but its giving Uncaught error. I tried many combo fo this. But not getting why its coming. Following is the code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export interface IHero {
  id: number;
  name?: string
}

export abstract class  Hero implements IHero{
  id: number;
  name: string;

  constructor(hero: IHero){
    this.id = hero.id;
    this.name = hero.name;
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent extends Hero{
  hero: IHero;
  title = 'Tour  of Heroes';
  data = { id: 1, name: 'nitu' };

  constructor(data){
    super(data);
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.id);
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
constructor(data){
    super(data);
}
```

to

```
constructor(){
    super(this.data);
}
```

Angular dependency injector does not know what the `data` parameter is and can't inject it.